# doesn't worry about what others think, independent confident

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

How would you describe someone who doesn't worry about what other people think? Someone who has the confidence to think for themselves. It could be a quality or adjective.  One word preferred

Comment: Voting to close as general reference. OP includes two viable options (independent and confident) and can find countless more by using a thesaurus.

Comment: Related (very): [Appropriate word for someone immune to embarrassment?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/330970/appropriate-word-for-someone-immune-to-embarrassment)

Answer (score 2):

*Maverick* was popular in the last U.S. presidential election cycle, though the candidates to whom it was applied would probably not be called *free spirited* or *nonconformist*, which have whimsical and countercultural connotations respectively.

If individual always acts without external input, I'd call him or her a *lone wolf*.

If s/he simply can't be bothered with external input, *nonchalant*.

If s/he wants to strike down convention actively, *iconoclastic*.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, he "marches to his own beat."

Self-assured would also work in this context.  Self-assured can have either either positive (he is confident) or negative (he is deluding himself) connotations.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever met "self-assured" with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Apathetic,
nonchalant,
indifferent,
detached,
disinterested,
unconcerned,
oblivious,
"cool."

Comment: Some of these have negative connotation.

Comment: I would argue in context, *all* of these have negative connotations.

Comment: Yeah, the only ones of these that could possibly have positive connotations are "nonchalant" and "cool", and the latter is (still) informal usage.

Answer (score 0):

One cliche answer is *free spirit*, or simply *spirited*. In some contexts, perhaps *irreverent*.